# Remote connection between Linux and window

Tags: linux, window, windows-xp-sp3

Is there any way I can take control of Linux machine, if I am using window xp.

Is there any software equivalent to windows netmeeting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use one of the following:

```
    NXServer
    Remmina (VNC incomming connections)
    RealVnc
    TightVNC
    ScreenConnect

...
```

or

```
TeamViewer in Wine (MS Emulator)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx).

Its allows you to control the mouse/keyboard like you were in front of the computer and share your audio/video and transfer files.

Futhermore, you don't have to worry about NAT routing either.